# User and superuser gets deleted automatically

Tags: django, authentication

I am working on a project where I am using AbstractUser class of django. I have already created the superuser. Whenever I create a new user either from interface or from admin, all the existing users get deleted including super user. I am not able to find any bugs in my code.

## models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from datetime import date

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,default=0)
    dateofbirth = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="No contact")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300,default="No address given")
    image = models.ImageField(default=None)
    manager_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_of_joining = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    date_of_termination = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8,default="inactive")
    role_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('emp_dashboard')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'portal', #App Name
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'portal.CustomUser'
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered
from django.apps import apps
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username','email','is_superuser']
    fieldsets = (
        (('User'), {'fields': ('username', 'email','is_active','is_superuser','is_staff','employee_id','dateofbirth','contact','address','image','manager_id','date_of_joining','date_of_termination','status','role_id')}),
    )
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)

for model in apps.get_app_config('portal').models.values():
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Comment: I see nothing in your code snippets that would cause such a behaviour so the issue is most probably in another part of the code. Do you have any signal handler ?

Comment: No. I have not created any signal handlers.